# php regex validate url fragment against list

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate the referrer in a page against a list of allowed sources. I have extracted the part of the referrer URL after the last "/" and now want to check it against a list of valid sources. Valid fragments will be in the form [filename][?id=nnn] with no other characters allowed, for example "view.php?id=1" is okay and "view.php?id=1&nasty=1" is invalid.

The method I am trying is:

```
$fragOK = preg_match('/'.implode('|', $okSrc).'\?id=[0-9]+$/', $frag);
```

where $okSrc is the array of valid source filenames and $frag is the extracted string. Obviously something is wrong with this because $fragOK === 1 with both of the examples I gave above. Can anyone explain where I am going wrong please?

Updating with var_dumps:

```
----------------------------------------------------
$okSrc
----------------------------------------------------
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "view.php"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "detail.php"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "request.php"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "overview.php"
}

----------------------------------------------------
$frag
----------------------------------------------------
string(21) "view.php?id=1&nasty=1"
```

Comment: Can you give a small sample list of valid source filename

Comment: Sure, there is one example in the question (view.php) but other valid filenames are detail.php, request.php, overview.php. I did it with an array because I want a simple way to add more in future.

Comment: Thanks, but still not clear how your urls to match would look like, can you update question with var_dump of $okSrc and $frag before call to preg_match

Comment: Updated. The fragment shown should be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the scripts inside a group:

```
$fragOK = preg_match('/(?:'.implode('|', $okSrc).')\?id=[0-9]+$/', $frag);
//              here __^^^                  and __^
```

You may want to use also `preg_quote` on $okStr to escape the dots.

Comment: That's spot on thank you. I'm pleased to see how close I was, and to learn something new. Thank you very much.

Comment: why ?:, he needs to match the filename from the list, adding parenthesis is enough, and dots in filename shouldn't effect but to be on safer side use of preg_quote is recommended.

Comment: @karmendra: because you don't need to capture, it' faster.

Comment: see his $okSrc array, if the $frag is view.php?id=1 it is a match what if $frag is somethingelse.php?id=1, it will match with your pattern, I beleive it shouldn't match.

Comment: @karmendra: Sorry I don't get you. What do you want to say?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE he wants to match strings ("view.php", "detail.php", "request.php" and "overview.php") from $okSrc array anything else should n't match. and that is the reason he is doing implode. Your code is same as `$fragOK = preg_match('/.*?\?id=[0-9]+$/', $frag);`; as good as not checking $okSrc.

Comment: @karmendra: What are you saying? Where the `.*?` comes from? Did you try my solution?

Comment: My bad, I get it now. `<?php
$okSrc = array("view.php","detail.php","request.php","overview.php");                                             

$frag = "view.php?id=10"; //should match this                                                      
$fragOK = preg_match('/(?:'.implode('|', $okSrc).')\?id=[0-9]+$/', $frag);                                           
echo $fragOK;                      

$frag = "abcd.php?id=10"; //should NOT match this
$fragOK = preg_match('/(?:'.implode('|', $okSrc).')\?id=[0-9]+$/', $frag);
echo $fragOK;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you are not having the strings surrounded by parenthesis.

see this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF0xO5/2)

Update: '.' in the view.php for example will not effect the match

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I am afraid I have no idea how to read the demo you linked - I'm not a regular user of regex. The answer below from JE SUIS CHARLIE works perfectly.

Comment: In fact if you see right-top EXPLANATION section on that link you have the entire regular expression explained in regular English. Great when you are starting to learn regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. I have bookmarked the site, and will try playing around with it when I next need a regex.